# RestKit delete and update functionality not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Currently I'm working with an iOS App which uses RestKit for communication.
I successfully retrieved and added data. But updating and deleting data from the database is not working.

I'm using the following code for adding new entry to database:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/tblTests" delegate:self];
RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://10.10.3.101/WcfService1/WcfDataService1.svc/"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

[venueMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"Name",@"name", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:venueMapping forKeyPath:@"value"];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/tblTests/" delegate:self];
RKObjectMapping* venueMappingS = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
venueMappingS.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[venueMappingS mapKeyPath:@"Name" toAttribute:@"name"];

RKObjectRouter *router = [[RKObjectRouter alloc] init];
[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/"];
[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setMapping:venueMappingS forKeyPath:@"value"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[venueMappingS inverseMapping] forClass:[Venue class]];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router = router;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

Venue *venueName = [[Venue alloc] init];
venueName.name = @"Midhun MP";
venueName.Id  = 12;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:venueName delegate:self];
```

It works perfectly, then I used the same code with only changing these two lines:

```
[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:venueName delegate:self];
```

to

```
[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/" forMethod:RKRequestMethodDELETE];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] deleteObject:venueName delegate:self];
```

This is not working !!!

My Venue Class:

```
@interface Venue : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int Id;

@end
```

And my JSON looks like:

```
{"value":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Midhun"},{"Id":12,"Name":"Midhun MP"}]}
```

I couldn't find any issues, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your updating/deleting an object and use a restful web services, you'll need to tell which object (with it's ID) should be updated. In RestKit you can achieve this by telling the router to use the given `:attribute`.

```
[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/:Id" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

BTW Seems like your using RestKit 0.10 that's getting outdating soon. Update to 0.20 and find some easier methods and the use of blocks that will be a lot easier.

Comment: I tried this and got error like: **Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)**

Comment: Could you use `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace); // Add to AppDelegate`, try again and post the full error message (with trace) as an addition do your answer?

Comment: `[router routeClass:[Venue class] toResourcePath:@"/tblTests/:Id\\.json" forMethod:RKRequestMethodDELETE];` You should make sure that your resource path is valid, and use the correct HTTP method. The above error is probably because your resource url is incorrect.